# Why does Linux allow users to remove the root directory?

Tags: linux, command-line

When I installed Linux for the first time in my computer, I always liked to use root, because I didn't need to add `sudo` and type the password every time I executed a command that needed root permissions.

So one day, I just wanted to remove a directory, and I ran `rm -rf  /`, so my system just broke down. I wonder why the Linux designers didn't forbid such a dangerous command.

Comment: It isn’t forbidden on Windows either.

Comment: I believe a modern Linux distribution won't allow this without `--no-preserve-root`

Comment: @DanielB I think this has nothing with Windows

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/640147/linux-protection-from-ourselves-root?rq=1

Comment: @fangxing was only adding that bit of information, inferring that being able to delete the root is not something uncommon.

Comment: Heh, the `rm -rf` promotion spamming hoax perpetrated on StackExchange has sure gained a lot of notoriety on the net. Why do most OS's allow users to recursively delete their file systems from the root... Because, somewhere along the line, mass deletions are necessary and if you're running the right flavor of Linux, you actually have protection against it, unlike other OS's.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the linked one. This asks why Linux allows `rm -rf /`, while the other is asking how to stop people from shooting themselves in the foot with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why shouldn't it allow you to do whatever you want to your own computer? Logging in as `root` or using `sudo` is saying to the machine, "I know what I'm doing." Preventing people from doing dubious things usually also prevents them from doing clever things, [as expressed by Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140102-00/?p=2183).

Besides, there's one singularly good reason to allow a user to torch the root directory: decommissioning a computer by completely erasing the OS and file system. (**Danger!** On some UEFI systems, `rm -rf /` can [brick the physical machine too](https://linux.slashdot.org/story/16/02/01/1357237/running-rm--rf--is-now-bricking-linux-systems).) It's also a reasonable thing to do inside a [`chroot` jail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

Apparently, people accidentally ran the command so much that a safety feature was added: `rm -rf /` does nothing on most systems unless `--no-preserve-root` is also supplied, and there's *no way* you can type that [by mistake](https://serverfault.com/q/587102/283572). That also helps guard against [poorly-written but well-intentioned shell scripts](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/01/17/scary_code_of_the_week_steam_cleans_linux_pcs/).

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** The simplest answer would be: why not? It's just a feature more, a tool that the operative system provides. You use it at your own risk, knowing what you're doing.

---

## Explanation

Using root as your user is a [very bad idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/16179/477290), since everything you execute is run with elevated privileges, a huge security flaw.

For example, if you downloaded a malicious program, or if the software installed in your computer had some critical bug, that could lead to devastating damage to your files and even your hardware.

Even if you're a bit too lazy to be writing `sudo` many times, there are some commands like `sudo -i`, that you can use for a while and then return to your normal privileges status. But I wouldn't recommend this unless you have more experience using the terminal.

However, this isn't attributable to Linux neither its developers. Actually, as @DanielB stated, **Windows allows this, too**. You have the liberty and the tools to do it, but that doesn't mean you have to.

There are packages that prevent you from `rm`ing your root directory, such as [Safe-rm](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm). That may be a good choice if you think there's a risk it happen again.
Other solutions and worarounds, like `rm`'s parameter `--preserve-root` are discussed in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/337098) Server Fault question.

Comment: Thanks your  nice answser , I say  'why Linux ... ',  is  just  because  I use Linux mostly. Sorry for my english is poor :) ,

Comment: No problem! It was just for clarifying that it's something that happens on other OS, a liberty that's there... just in case. ;)

Comment: downvoted, as it doesn't explain the asked question.

Comment: @toogley It's a bit difficult to answer to a question which hasn't got a specific answer like this one; still I've updated the question to be slightly more precise. Thanks for the feedback! :)